# More info - expand div

Tags: javascript

I'm after a bit of help with a "more info" script in Javascript/HTML.

Current code:

```
<div id="information">
    Content
    <div id="more_information" style="display:none;">
        More content
    </div>
<a href="#" onclick="showhide('more_information');">More information</a>​​​​​​​​
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function showhide(layer_ref) {

if (state == 'block') {
state = 'none';
}
else {
state = 'block';
}
if (document.all) { 
eval( "document.all." + layer_ref + ".style.display = state");
}
if (document.layers) {
document.layers[layer_ref].display = state;
}
if (document.getElementById &&!document.all) {
info = document.getElementById(layer_ref);
info.style.display = state;
}
}​
```

Cheers

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS:

```
function showhide(layer_ref) {
  var el = document.getElementById(layer_ref);
  var visible = el.style.display == 'block' // current state
  el.style.display = visible ? 'none' : 'block';
  return !visible; // new state (true=visible,false=invisible)
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="if(showhide('more_information')){this.innerHTML='Less information'}else{this.innerHTML='More information'};return false;">More information</a>​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Anyway I can remove the "More Information" once its clicked? or better yet, turn it into "Less Information".

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't work.

Comment: @Dean [Fixed. Working fine](http://codepad.viper-7.com/J4emYL) Next please just try debug the code by yourself

Comment: Thanks, yes I noticed the typo ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [jQuery](http://jquery.com), this makes it a lot easier:

```
jQuery("#information a").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).parent().find("#more_information").toggle();
});
```

Comment: How is this wrong? It shows/hides the div when clicking the link

Comment: Removed my downvote now that you added `.parent()`. Before that, it wouldn't work. Anyway, this is not a jQuery question, and does not require a jQuery answer. Plain js solutions are simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

It will work only if you have only one DOM element with id "more_information":

```
function showhide(nodeId) {
   var node = document.getElementById(nodeId);
   if (node) {
       node.style.display = node.offsetWidth ? 'none' : 'block';
   }
}​
```

If you have few similar structures on the page you should use this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="information">
    Content
    <div id="more_information" style="display:none;">
        More content
    </div>
    <a href="#" onclick="showhide(this); return false;">More information</a>​​​​​​​​
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function showhide(node) {
   var moreNode = node.previousSibling, i = 5;
   while (moreNode.nodeType != 1 && i--) {
      moreNode = moreNode.previousSibling;
   }

   if (moreNode && moreNode.nodeType == 1) {
       moreNode.style.display = moreNode.offsetWidth ? 'none' : 'block';
   }
}​
```